# Defining Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to ask, how to define Regex in C#

i have a text box, where user will write name of author, who should be find.
i want to define Regex which will find in HTML content

```
<span class ="author">John</span>
<span class ="song">Hooray</span>
```

something like:  user put John into textbox, program retrieves him  Hooray

My attempt:

```
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, @"<span class=("[\w\d]*")\sauthor=("[\w\d]*")>([\w\d]*)</span>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: You need to use an HTML parser and pass the value a user types into a text field as a part of an XPath expression.

Comment: Yes, a parser is the correct tool. Using regex on HTML is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Don't parse HTML using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, nothing good ever comes from using regex on HTML. However, if - and only if - the markup is as simple as in your example, you could probably get away with something like this:

```
    @"<span class=""author"">(?<author>[^<]+)</span>"
```

The authors name could be retrieved from match.Groups["author"].Value

Comment: Good answer, I'm very skeptical concerning the quality of the question. Shows a somewhat obvious lack of research